# Subsets and equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A \bigcup B = A \bigcup C$ then does $B = C$ ? I was thinking that it would be false because if $B$ is a subset of $A$, and $C$ is a subset of $A$, then $B \neq C$.

Comment: You are correct: it doesn't follow that $B=C$. But if it is true that $A \cup B = A \cup C$ for *all* sets $A$, then it is true that $B = C$. (Can you prove this?)

Comment: @SrivatsanNarayanan: Since it is true for every $A$ Take $A=\phi$ It gives that $B=C$ Am I Correct?

Comment: You know one "why" intuitively.  At the technical level, however, what you wrote is not quite right, after all we could have $B=C$.  When something is false in general, one shows this by producing an *explicit* counterexample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right.

An easy counterexample: $A=\{0,1\}$, $B=\{0\}$ and $C=\{1\}$.

You have $A\cup B=A\cup C=A$, but $B\ne C$.